# Time complexity of incrementing a binary counter?

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity

I have the following pseudocode for incrementing a binary counter:

```
 Increment(B)
    i=0
    while B[i]=1
       flip B[i] to zero
       increment i by 1
    b[i]=1
```

I have been told that the runtime is O(log n), but I can't see why - the loop looks like it might visit all the bits.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note `log n` is the width of `B` needed to contain a number `n`.

Comment: can u please elaborate like with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a binary counter representing the number n, then there will be a total of Θ(log n) different bits (since each bit represents exponentially larger and larger values). If you look at the quantity b, the number of bits, then it should be easy to see that the runtime of the above algorithm is O(b), since each bit is visited at most once. However, since b = Θ(log n), the time complexity ends up being O(log n).

Hope this helps!